# Twitter Gem Search method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter

My code is here

```
require 'twitter'



search = Twitter::Search.new.containing("obama")
```

it returns us

```
 #<Twitter::Search:0xb6881f9c @proxy=nil, @gateway=nil, @format=:json, @search_endpoint="https://search.twitter.com/", @consumer_key=nil, @adapter=:net_http, @endpoint="https://api.twitter.com/1/", @oauth_token_secret=nil, @query={:q=>["obama"], :tude=>[]}, @oauth_token=nil, @consumer_secret=nil, @user_agent="Twitter Ruby Gem 1.6.2", @cache=nil>
```

I want to search only public tweets that contain `obama`

How can i do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try

```
Twitter.search('Obama')
```

or

```
Twitter.search('Obama', options = {})
```

Also I noticed you are missing Authentication atributes. Take a look into [Twitter API Doc](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets) to make sure you have all the 'required' params.

PS: Do you want to search all the tweets that contains the string 'Obama' or all tweets with #Obama. The search result-set and the accuracy is different for both the searches.

Comment: undefined method `search' for Twitter:Module this error occurred

Comment: I fixed this problem with oathentication

Comment: I mentioned at the beginning of the post that you are missing Authentication attributes. Please mark this is answered if it helped you.