# How Do I search Twitter for a word with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, twitter

I have written code in Ruby that will display the timeline for a specific user. I would like to write code to be able to just search twitter to just find every user that has mentioned a word. My code is currently:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'oauth'
require 'json'

# Now you will fetch /1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json,
# returns a list of public Tweets from the specified
# account.


  baseurl = "https://api.twitter.com"
path    = "/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json"
query   = URI.encode_www_form(
    "q" => "Obama"
    )
address = URI("#{baseurl}#{path}?#{query}")
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new address.request_uri

# Print data about a list of Tweets
def print_timeline(tweets)
  tweets.each do |tweet|
  require 'date'
    d = DateTime.parse(tweet['created_at'])
    puts " #{tweet['text'].delete ","} , #{d.strftime('%d.%m.%y')} , #{tweet['user']['name']}, #{tweet['id']}"
  end
end

# Set up HTTP.
http             = Net::HTTP.new address.host, address.port
http.use_ssl     = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER

# If you entered your credentials in the first
# exercise, no need to enter them again here. The
# ||= operator will only assign these values if
# they are not already set.
consumer_key = OAuth::Consumer.new(
    "")
access_token = OAuth::Token.new(
    "")

# Issue the request.
request.oauth! http, consumer_key, access_token
http.start
response = http.request request

# Parse and print the Tweet if the response code was 200
tweets = nil
puts "Text,Date,Name,id"
if response.code == '200' then
  tweets = JSON.parse(response.body)
  print_timeline(tweets)
end
nil
```

How would I possibly change this code to search all of twitter for a specific word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets) suggests the URI your should be using for global search is `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json` and this means:

- Your `base_url` component would be `https://api.twitter.com`
- Your  `path` component would be `/1.1/search/tweets.json`
- Your `query` component would be the text you are searching for.

The `query` part takes a lot of values depending upon the API spec. Refer to the specification and you can change it as per your requirement.

Tip: Try to use `irb` (I'd recommend `pry`) REPL which makes it a lot easier to explore APIs. Also, checkout the [Faraday](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday) gem which can be easier to use than the default HTTP library in Ruby IMO.

Comment: I edited the code but I am running into an error when I run it, not pulling any data. Should the syntax be as the edit shows?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest approach would be to use 'Twitter' gem. Refer to [this](http://rdoc.info/gems/twitter/Twitter/API/Search) Link for more information and the result type of the search results. Once you have all the correct authorization attribute in place (oAuth-Token,oAuth-secret, etc) you should be able to search as

```
Twitter.search('Obama')
```

or

```
Twitter.search('Obama', options = {})
```

Let us know, if that worked for you or not.

p.s. - Please mark the post as answered if it helped you. Else put a comment back with what is missing.

Comment: That link is not finding a page. I already have all the tokens and keys in place. Where would Twitter.search() be placed in the code with this method?

Comment: now it should work. I had a typo over there. This is the raw url http://rdoc.info/gems/twitter/Twitter/API/Search

Comment: That makes much more sense. So can I place that code in the query section, or must it go somewhere else?

Comment: even with the above code, which i edited, I am running into a uninitialized constant Context::Twitter error.

Comment: please double check the authorization attributes. Is OAuth in place?

Comment: see on another thread of mine, people were able to search using this successfully. I am trying to understand why it didn't work for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16976123/twitter-gem-search-method/17030187#17030187

Comment: The current search code I have is returning a hash, while I need it to be in an array. With your method of entering the Twitter.search, where would that be entered in my current code to allow it to run, and what would i need to delete?

Comment: The response format is always in JSON and type is Tweet object https://dev.twitter.com/docs/platform-objects/tweets